# I am not able to store EditText data in val name

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helperMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/enter_the_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/input_hint_text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/helperMessage" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/createBirthdayButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="@string/create_birthday_card"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:onClick="createBirthdayCard"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameInput" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.birthdaygreet
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {
    val name= nameInput.editableText
    Toast.makeText(this,"Button was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
}
```

Main problem is accruing in this line I don't know why it is heppning
val name= nameInput.editableText //editableText is not working on nameInput.
Please let me know where I am mistaking in the code
[This is the problem that I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GrnX.png)

Comment: And where are you declare `nameInput` variable in your kotlin's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {
val name= findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameInput) .editableText.toString()
Toast.makeText(this,"Button was $name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared a nameInput variable therefore the compilation error. Declaring nameInput in the xml does not automatically make it an accessible variable. You need to assign the EditText to a variable in your activity by using: findViewById(R.id.nameInput)

Try the following:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var nameInput: EditText? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    nameInput = findViewById(R.id.nameInput)
}

fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {
    val name= nameInput.text
    Toast.makeText(this,"Button was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
}
```